# Reload changed java code in javacon module

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, ls2j

A part of my lotus application is written in java and the classes reside in a Java library. On a form using Lotus Script, I communicate with my Java classes using the module Javacon (LS2J).

When I change something in some Java class, the lotus script doesn't see the changes. I have to close the whole domino designer and open it again in order for the changes to take effect.

I tried:

- Closing Domino client only
- Clean/Build project or all projects
- Compile the java library alone

All of this didn't help. Is there a better way to reload the Java classes?

Comment: Did you try: Make a fake change in the lotusscript code that call the java (via LS2J) save the form. What do you mean by "Clean/Build project or all projects" in the external EDI or in Domino DESIGNER client?

Comment: I'm afraid something could be altered in the DB. I would create a new DB, add a simple code in a form that make the LS2J call, in java return a simple constant integer. RUN. then change the constant re run it take the change into account.

Comment: I tried something similar. A java class has a SayHello Method. I changed it to return another string and tried the methods above. Invaine!